# How to Create RequestBody from JSONObject?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using okhttp3.RequestBody to send request to server,
if I have JSONObject with data I need to send
I am writing code like this:

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                                .addFormDataPart("id", object.optLong(Comment.TASK_ID_JSON_TAG) + "")
                                .addFormDataPart("type", "IMAGE")
                                .addFormDataPart("latitude", object.optDouble(Comment.LATITUDE_JSON_TAG) + "")
                                .addFormDataPart("longitude", object.optDouble(Comment.LONGITUDE_JSON_TAG) + "")
                                .build();
```

now if I have JSONObject with large data is there a way to create RequestBody directly?
thanks for help.

Comment: please read these: [page1](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [page2](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [page3](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Ok, I did, what's the problem in my question?
Is it not clear?

Comment: Yes it is not clear, I adopt that any one will understands what you need. Instead provide your work and state what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can post all json object in one param ,and send it to server.

check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/34180100/1067963

```
public static final MediaType JSON
    = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use gson to serialize `(gradle -> implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7' )` and then do this -->  pay attention to `MediaType` and setbody function its just 2 lines of code :) and then send request use body... if you want to send `java object as JSON` do this

```
public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

@Override
protected void setBody() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String data = gson.toJson(yourObject);
    body = RequestBody.create(JSON, data);

}
```

//then you can build your request setting this body `( RequestBody body )`