# How to make a POST request by passing a object in Okhttp?

Tags: java, android, json, http-post, okhttp

This is my Json body :

```json
{
    "username": {
        "country": "IN", 
        "number": "9620494812"
    }, 
    "password": "119209"
}
```

I'm trying to make a POST request with `Okhttp` as follows:

```java
Username username = new Username("IN" , "9620494812");

JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();

try {
    postData.put("username" , username);
    postData.put("password" , "119209");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE , postData.toString());

Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://www.gruppie.in/api/v1/login")
        .method("POST" , body).build();
```

I have checked the request but i still get the error as

Response is :

```json
{"status":401,"type":"about:blank","title":"Unauthorized"}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179922/okhttp-post-body-as-json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your JSON, You have to send `JSON` request like this . Try this

```
    JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject userJson=new JSONObject();
    try {
        userJson.put("country","IN");
        userJson.put("number","9620494812");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        postData.put("username" , userJson);
        postData.put("password" , "119209");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... It's working correctly now... What mistake did i make in my code?