# How to send OkHttp post request with json multipart body along with a image file

Tags: android, okhttp, square

I want to send a post request in which I've to send some data which includes json formatted data and a image file.

When I'm sending request separately then its working fine, but does'nt wokring together.

Please help me here, how to acheive this.

**What I've used for sending json formatted data:**

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
postParam.put("title", "XYZ");
postParam.put("isGroup", "true");
postParam.put("ownerId", "123");
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put("1");
jsonArray.put("2");
jsonArray.put("2");
postParam.put("groupMembers", jsonArray.toString());
MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json");
JSONObject parameter = new JSONObject(postParam);
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, parameter.toString());
Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(postUrl)
            .addHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
            .post(body)
            .build();
```

Its working fine when I've not used the file.
But I've to send a image file as multipart data with this request, then how to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179922/okhttp-post-body-as-json

Comment: @Raghunandan, above is for json body, I'm talking about the post request which contains json body + file. The code mentioned by me is for json body and its working fine when I' uploading json only. Please let me know the answer when need to post both.

Comment: pls check MultiPart section https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Comment: @Raghunandan, I've already checked. But there is no option for the both type of data uploading.

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin usage**

Try using this piece of code. It worked in my case. And let me know if it works and make it the right answer (:

```
    private const val CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 15L
    private const val READ_TIMEOUT = 15L
    private const val WRITE_TIMEOUT = 15L

    private fun performPostRequest(urlString: String, jsonString: String, image: File, token: String): String? {
        /* https://github.com/square/okhttp#requirements
        OkHttp uses your platform's built-in TLS implementation.
        On Java platforms OkHttp also supports Conscrypt,
        which integrates BoringSSL with Java.
        OkHttp will use Conscrypt if it is the first security provider: */
        Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1)

        return try {
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(WRITE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()

            val body: RequestBody = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("parameterNameInServerSideJSON", jsonString)
                .addFormDataPart("parameterNameInServerSideImage", "test.jpeg", image.asRequestBody("image/jpg".toMediaTypeOrNull()))
                .build()

            val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(URL(urlString))
                .header("Authorization", token) // in case you use authorization
                .post(body)
                .build()

            val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
            response.body?.string()
        }
        catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }
```

I've used this version of okhttp

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.3.1'
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this to send files:

```
public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                        + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Type: "
                        + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }
```