# How to convert http c# to java in okhttp (android studio)

Tags: java, c#, android, okhttp

I have written following code in C#

```
public void call(){
    #region Post To Aws Onelink GpsData
    var endpointAwsCenter="https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    var tokenAwsCenter="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    var client = new RestClient(endpointAwsCenter);
    IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST); 
    request.AddHeader("x-api-key",tokenAwsCenter);
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("appliction/json", jsonAws, ParameterType.RequestBody); 
    var respAwsStr = client.Execute(request);
    #endregiona

}
```

Now I want to write similar code in java using okhttp library. This is what I tried so far

```
 mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("somParam", "someValue")
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .addHeader("x-api-key", tokenAwsCenter)
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .post(requestBody)
            .url(endpointAwsCenter)
            .build();
```

I dont know how to write in Java

```
request.AddParameter("appliction/json", jsonAws, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: add it as a body

Comment: Why do you create a MultipartBody in your Java code. This is not done in the C# source.

Comment: That would be a paid service if on some other side. by the way welcome to stack overflow and visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how stackoverflow works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a MultipartBody (which is actually not done in the C# code), simply create an `application/json` body instead:

```
MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonAws);
```

See [OkHttp Post Body as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179922/okhttp-post-body-as-json) as well