# OKHTTP how to pass JSON to FormBody

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

this code works:

```
    val rbody1: RequestBody = FormBody.Builder()
        .add("username", "100")
        .add("password", "123test123")
        .build()

    requestBuilder = Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(rbody2)
etc...
```

But I want to be able to pass a JSON string rather than having to encode each json parameter by hand.

```
val json = "{\"username\":100,\"password\":\"123test123\"}"

//completely fails, this is a okhttp3.RequestBody$Companion$toRequestBody$2
val MIMEType= "application/json".toMediaType()
val rbody2 = json.toRequestBody(MIMEType)
```

If I pass the rbody2 to the Request.Builder it fails. And I see no way to convert rbody2 to a FormBody, nor do I see a way to pass a json string into FormBody.Builder

This link does not answer my question:
[OkHttp Post Body as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179922/okhttp-post-body-as-json)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OkHttp Post Body as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179922/okhttp-post-body-as-json)

Comment: No, that does not work. I need to pass the JSON into FORMBODY if you read closely none of the answers do that. The key here is FORM.

Comment: How do I get this question to be not marked as duplicate?